# Laravel search query with two conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, search

Apologies if the title is unclear, I'm unsure how to word it..

I'm creating a search function for filtering orders. Every order is assigned a user id or parent id (if the user is a child user) which is used to associate orders with users.

Eg: userid, parentid, name, product, delivery.

My problem is: searching by name etc. will return all results of that name regardless whether you're associated by id.

So I essentially need: where userid or parentid = current userid
followed by the search conditions: orwhere name, orwhere product, orwhere delivery = search term.

I currently have this working by checking the db for all search term matches, and then unsetting the data in my controller to only output the ones matching userid or parentid. Is there a better way to do this?

Order controller

```
$data = app('App\Http\Controllers\DbController')->getordersbysearch($search);
        foreach($data as $row => $key){
        if($key->Userid != $id || $key->parentid != $id){
            unset($data[$row]);                
        }
        else{
            $key->Response = json_decode($key->Response);
        }
```

dbcontroller

```
         public function getordersbysearch($search){
    $result = DB::table('orders')->where("Name", 'like', '%' . $search['search'] . '%')->orWhere("product", 'like', '%' . $search['search'] . '%')->orWhere("delivery", 'like', '%' . $search['search'] . '%')->get();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the id to the function:

```
$data = app('App\Http\Controllers\DbController')->getordersbysearch($search, $id);
```

Then change your function to use this id:

```
public function getordersbysearch($search, $id) {
    $result = DB::table('orders')
        ->where(function($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('parent_id',$id)
              ->orWhere('user_id',$id);
         })->where(function($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where("Name", 'like', '%' . $search['search'] . '%')
              ->orWhere("product", 'like', '%' . $search['search'] . '%')
              ->orWhere("delivery", 'like', '%' . $search['search'] . '%');
         })->get();
    return $result;
}
```

In my opinion, this kind of controller shouldn't exist. "DbController" should be a different layer like Service or Model.

Comment: Thanks, I should have included that I'm already sending the id like so:         $search = ['Id'=>$id,
                   'search'=>$search
                ];

Comment: In this case, replace the `$id` with `$search['id'];`

Comment: Exactly! The function didn't filter the orders with user/parentid initially (I imagine I've made a small error somewhere) but is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. Can I ask why you think using a service or model is better than the dbcontroller? I'm relatively new to laravel..

Comment: It doesn't related to laravel itself, but to the MVC pattern. Controllers should be used only to get/send data between view and other layers. Basically, it only delegates to someone who will actually implement the business logic. You can google for MVC pattern, Service Layer pattern and read more.